# Что делать, если функция atof() не работает?

Tags: c

Функция atof() преобразует символьную строку не в double, как положено, а в int, в чем может быть проблема, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Код в студию.

Answer (score 1):

А как вы ее вызываете? Хотя бы код предоставили. Вот пример с сайта http://www.cplusplus.com

```
/* atof example: sine calculator */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
   double n,m;
   double pi=3.1415926535;
   char szInput [256];
   printf ( "Enter degrees: " );
   gets ( szInput );
   n = atof ( szInput );
   m = sin (n*pi/180);
   printf ( "The sine of %f degrees is %f\n" , n, m );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: делала аналогично как в этом примере

Comment: но ничего не получается

Comment: Код покажите. А то разговор ни о чем.

Comment: Может быть Вы по ошибке присваиваете результат atof() переменной, которая объявлена с типом int ?

Comment: @Katalinka При трансляции кода предупреждения были? Если да, то обсуждать нечего.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы переключили язык через setlocale() например на "rus" где разделителем является запятая, а не точка, то у вас не отобразится все что после точки.